# Tag monitoring?

Tags: discussion, retagging

So I've been on a bit of a re-tagging kick lately. I've been mostly removing inappropriate tags, like the [logic] tag which people tend to apply to *anything* that even references an argument.

Now, I think this is a good idea, since otherwise our tags will not serve as the signposts they are presumably intended for.

But I've realized, I should probably get some feedback from the community before unilaterally appointing myself the "tag police".

So, what does the community think? Is it important to regulate tagging and try to ensure appropriate tagging? Or, is it stepping on the toes of the OP?

Comment: A more uniform tagging policy is definitely something we should get our arms around. I would go ahead and retag away for the time being; we can always roll things back. Were there particular questions you might be concerned with?

Comment: @JosephWeissman Oh just a few I've recently re-tagged. I removed a [philosophy-of-science] tag from [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/what-are-the-consolations-of-atheism). And removed a [logic] tag (along with a few others, maybe [epistemology] too?) from [this question](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6511/is-there-a-strong-case-against-humes-is-ought-to-gap).

Comment: @Dennis I've been trying to do the same, sometimes tags seem just totally inappropriate, and I, too, have been worried whether somebody might find my actions inappropriate. I also wondered whether it's unfair, in a way, to retag really old and completely answered questions, because they get up in the "active" list and thus suppress other questions that still need an answer. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @iphigenie I'm of the opinion that a temporary bump in activity isn't troublesome enough to warrant accepting clearly inappropriate tags. They're meant to be signposts, as I see it, and so should point in the right direction.

Comment: @Dennis: I raised the same issue some time ago: http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/325/1582